# Itamaeを使ったufwの設定でexecuteを使わない方法

Tags: ubuntu, itamae

`Itamae`で`ufw`の設定をしたかったのですが以下のように`execute`を使う方法しか思いつきませんでした。

```
execute 'ufw allow 22/tcp'
execute 'ufw allow 80/tcp'
execute 'ufw allow 443/tcp'
execute 'ufw reload'
```

Itamaeの書き方の常識がよくわかっていないのですが、推奨される書き方などはありますか？

Comment: [itamae-plugin-resource-firewalld](https://rubygems.org/gems/itamae-plugin-resource-firewalld) や [itamae-plugin-resource-iptables](https://rubygems.org/gems/itamae-plugin-resource-iptables) はあるようなので、同じようにしてufw用のresourceを作るという手はありそうです。既製品は見つかりませんが・・・。